# GWT AutoBean - not serializing ArrayList<String>, other pojos ok?

Tags: gwt, javabeans

I can't get an ArrayList to serialize using the AutoBean mechanism. I'm using GWT 2.7. Here is my setup:

```
public interface IUser {
    String getName();
    void setName(String name);

    ArrayList<String> getFriends();
    void setFriends(ArrayList<String> friends);
}

public class User implements IUser {
    private String name;
    private ArrayList<String> friends;

    ... getters and setters for all members attributes ...
}
```

then my bean factory:

```
public interface AutoBeanFactoryImpl extends AutoBeanFactory {
    AutoBean<IUser> user(IUser inst);
}
```

and finally my usage:

```
ArrayList<String> friends = new ArrayList<String>();
friends.add("Mary");

User user = new User();
user.setName("Fritz");
user.setFriends(friends);

AutoBeanFactoryImpl factory = GWT.create(AutoBeanFactoryImpl.class);
AutoBean<IUser> bean = factory.user(user);
String json = AutoBeanCodex.encode(bean).getPayload();
```

The output json does not have the friends array. It has the name ok though. Why doesn't the string array get serialized? Do I need something special for that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you specified `ArrayList` instead of just plain `List` - in order to nicely generate code that fills in the gaps between Java and JSON, autobeans only want to work with interfaces. Aside from getters and setters, AutoBeans have special support for `List`, `Set` (which is just a `List` without duplicates in the JSON), and `Map`. If you specify a particular implementation, the AutoBean tooling can't always handle it.

Feel free to pass in an `ArrayList` instance, but declare your getter and setter to be of type `List`.

---

As an aside, those collections can be of any type that AutoBeans can otherwise handle - including numbers, booleans, strings, dates, and any other bean-like interface that also conform to what AutoBeans can deal with.

Comment: Hi Colin, yeah that worked, but then I ran into this bug: https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/6903 I don't think it's fixed yet, so I'm doing the crazy workaround in the original post - it almost defeats the purpose of auto serializing! Thanks

Comment: Huh! Wonder how that slipped through the cracks. I just got a fix in for Java8 and autobeans for gwt 2.8, maybe i'll take a look at this this weekend...